# Sending keys to cmd line from VBA loses special keys

Tags: vba, cmd

I'm writing a VBA macro that will send a string to the command line like below:

```
str = "SELECT (edr.VersionName + ' ' + edr.BuildName)"
RSP = Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC"), vbNormalFocus)
SendKeys str
```

But the issue comes that the special keys like ( and + are lost in translation; the command line ends up like below:

```
SELECT edr.VersionName  ' '  edr.BuildName
```

How do I prevent those special characters from being lost in the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the '+' symbols to show up by using this string:

```
str = "SELECT (edr.VersionName += ' ' += edr.BuildName)"
```

In the `SendKeys` function in VBA, the '+' symbol is used to indicate the {SHIFT} key.  So, {SHIFT}=, is actually the '+' symbol; at least on my keyboard.

Using that logic, '+9' and '+0' should give you '(' and ')' but I haven't gotten those to work yet.

**EDIT**

Ok, you can get the parentheses to show up, but you kind of have to include them twice:

```
str = "SELECT +9" & "(edr.VersionName += ' ' += edr.BuildName)" & "+0"
```

Again, keep in mind, the above string works for my keyboard (standard English).  If you are using a different keyboard layout, the characters after the '+' signs will most likely be different.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I found out another way to display those special characters, by enclosing it with {} it will show up in my command line. Thanks for the help!